# How to access the property of List <T> subclasses?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i've a Method which gets a List where T : Item.
How do i access the property from the Subclasses of Item?

```
private void CreateShopItem<T>(Transform itemTemplate, Transform shopScrollView, List<T> shopItemList) 
where T : Item {

shopItemList.Name //this works
shopItemList.power //this is a property from the class cooling and i cant access it



}
```

Ive 4 subclasses from the base class Item but i can only access the properties from the Class Item

Item Class:

```
public class Item
{
public int Id;
public string Name;
public double Cost;
public Sprite Sprite;
public bool IsPlaced;
public Vector3 Position;

public Item()
{
    Id = 0;
    Name = "Default";
    Cost = 0;
    Sprite = null;
    IsPlaced = false;
    Position = Vector3.zero;
}

public Item(int id, string name, double cost, Sprite sprite, bool isPlaced, Vector3 position)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Cost = cost;
    this.Sprite = sprite;
    this.IsPlaced = isPlaced;
    this.Position = position;

}

}
```

Sub Class Cooling:

```
public class Cooling : Item
{
public float power;
public float temp;

public Cooling(int id, string name, double cost, Sprite sprite, bool isPlaced, Vector3 position, 
float power, float temp)
{
    base.Id = id;
    base.Name = name;
    base.Cost = cost;
    base.Sprite = sprite;
    base.IsPlaced = isPlaced;
    base.Position = position;

    this.power = power;
    this.temp = temp;
}


}
```

What would be a way to access the property of all subclasses from the Base Class?

Comment: Just a style comment but all of your properties in `Item` start with an uppercase letter while the two specific to `Cooling` start with a lowercase.letter

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking the code to do doesn't make logical sense. When you use a generic type:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
         // example code here
    }
}
```

You are saying that you're going to be using a type (`T`) but you're not really sure yet which type you'll be using. The type will be specified at a later stage. The only assumption made by the compiler is that your `T` will derive from `object`.

This is okay, but that also means that you can't actually use this `T` with any more precision than you can use `object`. In the above example, you could call `this.Value.ToString()` because `T` is definitely an `object` (and `object` has the `ToString()` method), but you cannot call `this.Value.Power` because `T` is not known to be of the type `Cooling` (or a subtype).

You are able to influence what the compiler knows about the specific type that `T` will be. You've already done so by specifying that `T` will definitely be some sort of `Item` (i.e. class or subclass)

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Item
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
         // example code here
    }
}
```

Because the expectation is now that `T` is not just an `object` but also an `Item`, the compiler allows you to handle your `T` type with every known property/method of the `Item` type. You could access things like:

```
this.Value.Name
this.Value.Cost
this.Value.Sprite
```

Because these are properties of the `Item` class which you can definitely expect to see on *any* subclass of `Item`, you are allowed to access them when dealing with a `T where T : Item` generic type parameter.

---

You're trying to access a specific type's property (`Cooling`), without having told the compiler that your generic type is definitely going to be a (sub) class of `Cooling`.

That directly contradicts the core premise of using a generic type, i.e. treating a range of possible types using the **same** (generic) code. If that generic code were to only work with one specific type (i.e. `Cooling`), then there'd be no point in trying to make `CreateShopItem` work for any type that is not `Cooling` or one of its subtypes.

You need to go back to the drawing board with what it is that you want.

If I can assume that it is correct that `CreateShopItem` should work for *any* `Item` class, then you should inherently be able to write code that is able to handle *any* `Item` object without needing to know the specific concrete class being used.

---

*I am very intentionally ignoring upcasting here because it's a bad approach that tries to cover for a bad design. Generic type upcasting is rarely a good idea. It violates OCP (in all but exceedingly rare examples), and would not be a good idea in this particular scenario anyway.*

Answer (score 0):

Normally if a method needs to access a field/property this field would be included in the type that it accepts. While you can cast the item into a derived type, if you have to do it why accept the base type in the first place?

The problem is that if you use `if`s or `case` when you add a new type you need to remember to come back to this piece of code and update it.

---

BTW. Use properties, not fields. It is the standard way:

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id { get };
```

Comment: _"The problem is that if you use ifs or case when you add a new type you need to remember to come back to this piece of code and update it."_ For reference, this is specifically what [the open-closed principle (OCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) is all about: not having to update logic from existing classes when you create a new type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the example that you show for the this one works and this one doesn't should be wrong because the reference that you are using is a List (List for your example) and the both of them will not work unless you get the element that you want to change from that list (with a loop or maybe with LINQ First() etc)

Secondly, If you want to access a field from a subclass while you have a base class object. You need to cast it to that subclass. **For example:**

```
class Item{
   ...
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public double Cost;
}

class Cooling : Item {
   ...
   public float power;
}

//Example method to call 
private void CreateShopItem<T>(Transform itemTemplate, Transform shopScrollView, List<T> shopItemList) 
where T : Item {

var firstItem = shopItemList().First(); // taking the first element just for example

firstItem.Name = "foo"; // this is fine

var coolingItem = (Cooling) firstItem;
coolingItem.power = 1000; // now this is also fine
}
```

This will fix your current case but I do not recommend to do it because as the subclasses increase this can turn into a big mess of casting disaster between classes.
I recommend to check out **boxing/unboxing** topic on C# for future use and best practices.